# Logic involving processing on data (from DB) in ViewModel or Model?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, linq-to-entities

I'm developing an application using WPF. The pattern that I'm using for it is obviously MVVM. Also I'm using Entity Framework ORM and LINQ-to-Entities to query the EF objects.

My understanding of MVVM is that the View should have no code-behind and only knowledge it should have of the ViewModel is that the ViewModel contains certain properties with which the View is bound and also it contains commands to handle events of the view. Whereas the Model contains only code to get data from DB.

In my model classes I have just written functions which directly query EF objects using Linq-to-entities. The processing that I need to perform on the data before assigning it to properties in VM is either present in the VM or in classes present in the VM project. Just to mention here, that I have 3 projects - View, ViewModel and Model.

My question here is that, can I keep those functions (which involve processing on data from DB) in the VM project or should it be in the Model project? If in ViewModel project, should it be in the concerned VM or in separate classes present in the VM project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the commonly used practice is to delegate the business logic to the service layer and perform business logic using Repository Pattern. As mentioned in other answers, the ViewModel should decorate the model with view specific properties and commands which handle UI interactions. By its own defination the Model should have all the logic for manipulating the data.

If you are following Service Oriented Architecture, then the ViewModel can be injected with a service. The service is responsible for perfoming the business functions. These business functions are mostly done on the persisted data. And that logic can be abstracted nicely using any of the ORM tools and technologies like EF or NHibernate. You can do a google search for Repository Pattern which can be helpful if you follow this architecture.

It is not necessary to use the Repository Pattern if you don't need it. You can still use EF directly from your service layer. Advantage of having the repository is that it acts like a mapper between the persistance layer(database) and the domain layer(model).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

They should be in the Model project, the ViewModel is just a representation what your View expects, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Responsibility are:
Model -> get data from db, service etc and expose data through domain objects. Not concerned with how the data will be displayed. Only concerned with business logic involving the domain objects.

ViewModel -> read data from model and decorate them so that they can be displayed in View in proper format. Expose Properties that the View can bind to fetch the data. Also Expose Commands that the view can call on user inputs.

View -> as per data received from VM through DataBinding, display the data using a nice DataTemplate or UserControl. Bind to VM Commands to call on user inputs.

Ideally ViewModel is concerned only with displaying the data on the UI and not with modifying the model. It receives a model object in its constructor and exposes properties to be used by the view through Data binding. The Model is not aware of the ViewModel. Whenever the model data changes, the ViewModel can be notified of the changes either by event thrown by model which VM subscribes to. Or the VM has to query the model whenever the View calls the properties getter in VM for data.

The Model should expose the properties irrespective of how they will be displayed. So it should not do any processing on the properties. The ViewModel may decorate the data received from Model as per requirement of the View.

Comment: "Whenever the model data changes, the ViewModel can be notified of the changes either by event thrown by model which VM subscribes to". Can you elaborate this point with an example?
If ViewModel cannot modify data and Model cannot do any processing on the data, then where should that logic reside?

Comment: Model should change the data within itself as per business logic. Whenever it changes its data it can raise events to notify VM of the data change. If VM needs to change this data for better display, it should read the data from model into its own field, change it and expose changed data through property. VM should not change model data. It is only concerned with how the data will look like and not conerned with business logic.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's better to move the database processing functions to the Model project because it's possible that too much responsibility will lay on the ViewModel.

I'll try to show an example:

Assume we have a class `SomeViewModel` with properties `IsHighlited` and `Item`, something like this:

```
class SomeViewModel
{
    public bool IsHighlighted
    {
        get 
        { 
            /* View logic here */
        }
    }

    public SomeClass Item
    {
        get
        {
            /* Retreiveing an item from database */
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you need to modify a view logic you must modify the `SomeViewModel` class (it's ok), but when you need to modify a database communication logic you also need to modify the same class, which is not so good yet.

[Single responsibility principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) says:

> There should never be more then one
>   reason for a class to change.

As a result, if you keep things as they are now, you can run into unnecessary big complexity of your code in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to use the Entity Framework together with the MVVM pattern.

Comment: No attempt to answer the question here, and yet another place for you to link your WAF. You don't even link to any specific, helpful page on the site.